# Why isn't my Qmaster cluster showing up in Compressor?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I created and added two computers to a Qmaster cluster in Qadministrator so that a Compressor export would be faster. However, the cluster doesn't show up in Compressor! What do I do? I have no clue how to fix this, but I really need the extra processing power from the other computer.

Comment: Which of these steps is failing on you? [Compressor: Troubleshooting basics](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1888)

Comment: @bmike I have gone up to the point of repairing permissions but not beyond that yet. I will repair permissions and reinstall if necessary, and report back.